# How can I tag a component in AEM 6.1?

Tags: aem, tagging

I need to know if is possible tag a component button like a 'CTA' (call to action).
In the Adobe documentation i found how tag a page but not a component

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tagging is supposed to be associated with content e.g. pages, assets etc. Components are more of part of code and would not be tagged. you can create component groups as pointed out by d33t.

Answer (score 0):

You mean probably to add a component to a group? There are no tags for components. You can group one or more components by adding the following property to the component's node:

```
componentGroup="Your group"
```